# How to fix error "could not convert <brace enclose initilizer list> to Node"

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an array of the struct `node`. Does anybody know how to declare the constructor in the class `hashing` to create an array of `node`. In my code is an error that says could not convert `<brace enclosed initializer list>` to `Node`:

```
template <typename E, size_t N=7>
class Hashing : public Container<E> {
    struct Node {
        E value;
        Node *next;
        Node (E value) : value (value), next(nullptr) {}
        E getValue() { return value; }
        void putValue(E value) { this->value = value; }
        Node *getNext() { return next; }
    };

    size_t nmax;
    size_t n;
    Node * values;
    Node field[N] = {};

public:
    Hashing(): n(N) {};
```

Comment: Can not see instantiate the class. Where an error should occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your `Node` class is not default constructable.  When you do

```
Node field[N] = { };
```

It tries to default construct each element in the array.  Since you you have a user defined constructor the default constructor provided by the compiler is suppressed.  If you add one like

```
Node(): value(0), next(nullptr) {}
```

The code will compile.